# Javascript change from cognos 10 to cognos 11.1.7

Tags: javascript, cognos-10

We recently switched over from Cognos 10 to Cognos 11.1.7, this code works fine in Cognos 10 and as we moved to Cognos 11 it broke some of the functionality. I was able to narrow down to this piece of code and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with it. I added some alerts to do some checks and it is not able generate any value for 'mmid' field and it is coming up undefined after it goes through the loop.

```
                       function isChecked ()
                                            {
                                            // get the handle for the checkbox prompt - add div around them to distinguish
                                            var prompt1 = document.getElementById('checkBox1');
                                            var sel_list='';
                                            var node_list = prompt1.getElementsByTagName('input');
                                            var mmid_list = prompt1.getElementsByTagName('mmid');  //---- '[0].firstChild.data;'
                                            for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++)
                                            {
                                            var node = node_list[i];
                                            var mm_item=mmid_list[i];
                                            if (node.getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox') {
                                            if (node.checked) {
                                            // do something if checked - build string list of rowids
                                             alert("Checkbox "+(i+1)+" is checked");
                                             alert('got here '+i+'['+mm_item.value+']');
                                            if (sel_list == '') {
                                            sel_list = mm_item.value;
                                            } else {
                                            sel_list= sel_list + ", " + mm_item.value;
                                            }
                                            }
                                            }
                                            }
```